# Recursive method to remove all odd digits from an int

Tags: java, recursion

I'm having trouble writing a recursive method that is meant to remove any odd digits from an int - for example: `evenDigits(123456)` should return `246`. My first thought was to turn the int into a string and cycle through that way but the question explicitly states you cannot use Strings to solve it.

Any help is appreciated

EDIT: This is what I have so far, I'm not sure if its along the right lines, but I cannot figure out what to do if the last digit was to be even

```
public static int evenDigits(int n)

if(n==2)
{
    return 2;
}

if(n==1)
{
    return 0;
}

if((n%10)%2==1) //if the last digit is odd
{
    return evenDigits(n/10); //run it again without the last digit
}
```

Comment: Hint: `123456 % 10` is 6, and `123456 / 10` is 12345.

Comment: I think I grasp this part of the question but I cannot wrap my head around how to do it recursively

Comment: Identify why recursion can be used, then define base condition to exit recursion by returning what value??

Comment: Figure out a function that takes your int as an input, does something simple that makes sense, then needs to do the same thing again so it calls itself with a different input, and finally it returns the result

Comment: One way you can approach this is to start with a smaller test case, like "12" or "23" and try to do it by hand.  Note carefully what steps you take, then try to reproduce those steps in an algorithm.  Debug that a few times to make sure the program is following the steps you took as closely as possible.  This will usually get you at least close enough where people will help you figure out the last parts to get it working.  But you do need to make an effort.

Comment: I realised that, sorry will edit now

Comment: So, this doesn't even compile.  You don't always return a value, and that's a syntax error.  If `if((n%10)%2==1)` is NOT true, what do you propose to do?

Comment: To continue @markspace's thought, sometimes I'll write non-recursive code for simpler examples to make sure I understand the algorithm before I try and write recursive code to handle more complex examples.

Answer (score 3):

Since its obviously the homework, I can't provide a full solution, however here are some hints:

When you define recursion you should think when you stop (a stop condition).
If you follow the hints provided by @marksplace - then you will probably stop when the recursion will reach the point where no digits have left.

Another thing you should think of is where to store the result "accumulated so far". You'll pass it through the recursion. Its even called "accumulator" in the literature.
So when you reach the stop condition you'll return the accumulator. In addition think about how exactly you are going to update the accumulator.

Here is an example of how it can work without diving into the code:

1. 123456 
   a. Last digit is 6, its even, preserve it, update an accumulator (=6)
   b. recursive call for 12345
2. 12345 - last digit is odd - remove it, 
   b. recursivce call for 1234
3. 1234  - last digit is 4 - its even, preserve it, update the accumulator 6 -> 46 (here you should think about the math formula of such an update)

....

At last - stop when you reach the point, where there are no digits, accumulator will contain the answer

Good luck!